# resume next only works with some scripts vb

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I am trying to use resume next, so my users don't see the errors but i will set it up to send me an email.
How come the resume next works on a simple error like this:

```
x = 10
y = 0
z = x / y
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
MsgBox "There's been an error #1"
end if
```

But this one, throws a 500 page

```
Set objMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message") 
objMessage.Subject = "testing this out" 
objMessage.From = "devorah@cucumber.com" 
objMessage.To = "devorah.fleisher@oorah.org"
objMessage.HTMLBody = "this is a test" & "gfjhg
hgfjfg"
objMessage.Send
```

Microsoft VBScript compilation error '800a0409'

Unterminated string constant

Answer (score 3):

`On Error Resume Next` enables error handling for **runtime** errors, not **syntax** errors. You have a syntax error in this statement:

```
objMessage.HTMLBody = "this is a test" & "gfjhg
hgfjfg"
```

VBScript doesn't support multiline string literals, so you need to replace that with something like this:

```
objMessage.HTMLBody = "this is a test" & "gfjhg" & vbNewLine & "hgfjfg"
```

Comment: Actually, it does support, by using the "_" character.

Comment: @ShadowWizard The `_` character is for line continuation, i.e. continuing a *statement* (not a string) in the next line. Each string literal must still be on one line. If VBScript supported multiline string literals (which it doesn't) you'd be able to have string literals span more than one line, like in the statement that raised the error for the OP.

Comment: True, but still think it's worth to mention the ability to have command span several lines, even if not for a single string literal.

Answer (score 0):

While [the first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29219332/447356) is correct, it does not suggest alternatives to what you're trying to do.

If you want the code to be more readable by spanning few lines, you can do it using the "_" (Statement Break) operator:

```
objMessage.HTMLBody = "this is a test" &_
                      "gfjhg" &_
                      "hgfjfg"
```

If your goal is generate actual line break in the email  body, you have to add `<br />` tags:

```
objMessage.HTMLBody = "this is a test<br />" &_
                      "gfjhg<br />" &_
                      "hgfjfg"
```

Comment: While it is more readable I find it unuseful especially if you want to comment one line, so I tend to build up a variable first like `msg = msg & "this is a test<br />"` followed by `msg = msg & "gfjhg<br />"` then once concatenated `objMessage.HTMLBody = msg`. That way if I wanted to comment out `msg = msg & "gfjhg<br />"` I can without breaking the rest.

Comment: @Lankymart sure, same here actually but I was giving the OP proper syntax for the way he/she are trying to use. Taking it even further, I would use array of lines, then Join it with `<br />`. :)

Comment: Yeah that's fine. Thing is we don't know whether they are trying to span commands across lines or they purposefully broke their code expecting the `On Error Resume Next` to deal with it which we have established will not happen.

Comment: @Lankymart huh, never occured to me.